# How to use pe:inputNumber with BigDecimal

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Whats the proper/best way to use `pe:inputNumber` for exact big decimals? I have to accept currency input which can have up to 4 decimals, and must not be rounded. Right now I am doing the following:

```java
public void withdraw(Number amount) {
 BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(amount.doubleValue());
 // process 
}
```

and

```html
<pe:inputNumber roundMethod="S" decimalPlaces="4" symbol="#{applicationBean.currentCurrencySymbol}" required="true" value="#{flowScope.Amount}"/>

<p:commandButton value="Proceed" type="submit" ajax="true" actionListener="#{myBean.withdraw(flowScope.Amount)}"
</p:commandButton>
```

My concern is that value gets converted to `Double` internally by `InputNumber` which can potentially lead to rounding errors when I convert it into `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

The PrimeFaces Extensions `InputNumber` has been moved to PrimeFaces a while ago. The [source of the renderer](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/inputnumber/InputNumberRenderer.java) is open. There you'll find that [submitted values are directly used to instantiate a `BigDecimal`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/f9f4a260ca82d4cf1931196f50ba1f4d18d05da3/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/inputnumber/InputNumberRenderer.java#L89):

```java
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(submittedValue);
```

See also the showcase for an example with an example with a `BigDecimal`: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml